# $^nC_r$ summation series

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem

Given, COROLLARY 3 in Kennith H Rosen Discrete Mathematics book,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k} \binom{n}{k} = 3^{n}$$

Is this below mentioned result valid too?
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} = 3^{n}$$

If not, then how to solve it?

Comment: Neither result is true as written (try $n=2$ for example). Do you mean to include binomial coefficients in the sums?

Comment: @GregMartin, sorry for typos. I've updated the problem statement by including binomial coefficients.

Comment: @GregMartin i've tried for n=2,3 &4 and it produces same result. So, can i conclude that it is true?

Comment: @Dead you can't just assume that something is true, by just putting some values. You have to prove it, that's another head-ache.

Comment: If the first one is true, then the second one will also be true. Because $$\binom{n}{k} =\binom{n}{n-k}$$ The first result is true, by expanding $ (2+1)^n $ using binomial theorem.

Comment: Hint: what is $(x+y)^n$?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari, i got it. As suggested by Jujustum if i put x=1, and y=2 in first equation, i will get first result. Just by swapping values of x and y, i'll get second result. Seems like game of intuition.

Comment: @Dead yeah, intuition helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both statements are true.

Proof

By Binomial Theorem, we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^k = (x+1)^n $$

Let x=2, we have $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^k\binom{n}{k} = 3^n  \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Now define k' = n - k so that k = n - k'

It follows that
$$\sum_{k'=0}^{n} 2^{n - k'}\binom{n}{k'} = 3^n$$
since k' is a dummy variable, we can call it k again without loss of generality to get
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{n -k}\binom{n}{k}  = 3^n \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

The conclusion follows from equations (1) and (2).

QED